# store integer value in complex variable

Tags: c++, integer, complex-numbers

Its very simple but Iam unable to remove error. I want to store integer value in complex variable.

```
int int2 =2;
comp *cal = int2;
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't want the `*`; that makes it a pointer, not a complex variable. And how is `comp` defined? If it has an implicit constructor that takes a numeric type, then `comp cal = int2;` should work.

Comment: again !..plz read FAQ before asking a questn .

Comment: If you are lost on how to deal with complex numbers in C++, take a look at the `std::complex` class (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using standard complex numbers (that is, `comp` is an alias for `std::complex<something>`):

```
comp cal = int2;
```

If `comp` isn't a standard complex type, then we'll need to see how it's defined; there's no way to guess how it might work.

**UPDATE**: Regarding your comment: since it's a custom aggregate type, and assuming `Q` is the real part:

```
comp cal = {0, int2};
```

although you really should consider using standard types instead.

Regarding the rest of your comment: Why on earth do you have to use a pointer? That's insane. But if you really need one:

```
comp cal_ = {0, int2};
comp *cal = &cal_;
```

or if you need dynamic allocation for some reason (which you almost certainly don't; and if you do, you should be using smart pointers not raw pointers):

```
comp *cal = new comp{0, int2};
// and don't forget to delete it when you've finished with it
delete cal;
```

or if you're stuck with the pre-2011 language:

```
comp *cal = new comp;
cal->I = 0;
cal->Q = int2;
```

But to reiterate, whatever you think you have to do, you almost certainly don't want a pointer here.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I have to use comp * ,  not only comp. Any other technique. comp is defined as                                typedef struct 
{
 float I;

 float Q;
} comp;

Comment: @Annie: OK, I've updated the answer to show how to initialise your type. But I'm sure you don't have to use `comp*`; that would be insane.

Comment: Thanks alot. I knew that was simple, but wasnt coming to mind.